# Boost.Asio is the handler called after that the post?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I need to post a lamda to an `io_context` but I want to have the guarantee that the handler is executed only after the `post()` call. Following a simplified snippet:

```
auto l = [] { cout << "hello lambda"; };

int f(asio::io_context& io) {
  io.post(l);
}

int main() {
  asio::io_context io;
  thread th{[&io] { io.run(); };

  f(io);
  cout << "hello main";

  th.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it guarantee that "hello main!" is alayws called before "hello lamda"?

Comment: `Is it guarantee that "hello main!" is alayws called before "hello lamda"?` No. Two threads, no guarantees at all.

Comment: `run` returns when there are no handlers to be called. You have races in your code. You dont know if `io.run()` will be called after `post`, if not, nothing happens - your lambda will not be called at all.

Answer (score 2):

> PS I have taken the liberty of threating the question as *"Is it guarantee that "hello main!" is alayws called before "hello lamda"?"* because *"I want to have the guarantee that the handler is executed only after the post()"* is trivially true. That's because handlers [are guaranteed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) to only be executed on a thread currently running `run()/poll()` on an execution context

Swatting some syntactical errors and the missing return statement [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1639c1a64a06eb9) still has the race condition as described in the comments:

The thread running the io service may return before `post` ever gets a chance to run.

There are two typical approaches to solve this:

### Using a work guard

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0d5d38fd5abddb0)**

```
boost::asio::io_context io;
auto work = make_work_guard(io);
std::thread th{[&io] { io.run(); }};

f(io);
std::cout << "hello main\n";

work.reset();
th.join();
```

### Using the `thread_pool`

Recent Boost versions introduced a full featured threadpool:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4cd47f54f3ef00f)**

```
boost::asio::thread_pool io(1); // one thread

f(io.get_executor());
std::cout << "hello main\n";

io.join();
```

### Ordering Tasks: Single Service Thread

The most direct way is to simply post them all in order:

```
post(io, [] { std::cout << "hello main\n"; });
f(io.get_executor());
```

This means that `hello main` will always occur before the lambda posted from `f`.

### Ordering: Multiple Service Threads

If you have a true pool:

```
boost::asio::thread_pool io(10);
```

You can use a strand:

```
auto strand = make_strand(io);
post(strand, [] { std::cout << "hello main\n"; });
f(strand);
```

This still guarantees the ordering of the tasks in the same way.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064b35a7fd07891e)**

Prints

```
hello main
hello lambda
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, can you tell me why the first version, with guards, it's working?

Comment: The [executor work guard](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html) just [prevents the IO service ``run()` loop from returning early](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard/executor_work_guard/overload1.html). Note that [that version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0d5d38fd5abddb0) did ***not*** do anything to ensure ordering of the output statements. I treated these issues separately for clarity.